# NVD3 not formatting dates correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to modify the stacked area chart example for NVD3. I can draw the chart with my own data and everything works fine. The data parsing seems to not be working correctly, however. Like in the NVD3 example, I've converted my dates to Unix time, like in the NVD3 examples, and these are the first values in the data. The second values are the counts. The data draws fine, but the dates are all put as 01/17/1970. An example can be seen [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kxh05ciljlrb41l/Screenshot%202014-08-02%2016.07.01.png).

My data looks like:

```
var data = [
{'values': [[1403236800, 573], [1403323200, 632], [1403409600, 691],
    [1403496000, 882], [1403582400, 898], [1403668800, 869], [1403755200, 853],
    [1403841600, 787], [1403928000, 596], [1404014400, 505], [1404100800, 877],
    [1404187200, 813], [1404273600, 816], [1404360000, 754], [1404446400, 765],
    [1404532800, 531], [1404619200, 501], [1404705600, 786], [1404792000, 840],
    [1404878400, 963], [1404964800, 857], [1405051200, 909], [1405137600, 620],
    [1405224000, 694], [1405310400, 879], [1405396800, 926], [1405483200, 895],
    [1405569600, 1044], [1405656000, 1201], [1405742400, 869], [1405828800, 757],
    [1405915200, 1048], [1406001600, 972], [1406088000, 889], [1406174400, 941],
    [1406260800, 641], [1406347200, 477], [1406433600, 538], [1406520000, 780],
    [1406606400, 873], [1406692800, 757], [1406779200, 427], [1406865600, 37]],
    'key': 'Stream1'},
{'values': [[1403236800, 782], [1403323200, 843], [1403409600, 791],
    [1403496000, 1020], [1403582400, 1059], [1403668800, 1062], [1403755200, 1231],
    [1403841600, 1235], [1403928000, 801], [1404014400, 689],
    [1404100800, 1095], [1404187200, 908], [1404273600, 972], [1404360000, 924],
    [1404446400, 775], [1404532800, 381], [1404619200, 488], [1404705600, 895],
    [1404792000, 1081], [1404878400, 1035], [1404964800, 923],
    [1405051200, 1036], [1405137600, 736], [1405224000, 803], [1405310400, 985],
    [1405396800, 1186], [1405483200, 1095], [1405569600, 1328],
    [1405656000, 1229], [1405742400, 1218], [1405828800, 787], [1405915200, 1164],
    [1406001600, 1100], [1406088000, 1197], [1406174400, 927], [1406260800, 803],
    [1406347200, 670], [1406433600, 588], [1406520000, 850], [1406606400, 780],
    [1406692800, 699], [1406779200, 488], [1406865600, 37]],
    'key': 'Stream2'},
{'values': [[1403236800, 211], [1403323200, 211], [1403409600, 294], 
[1403496000, 367], [1403582400, 373], [1403668800, 361], [1403755200, 404],
    [1403841600, 450], [1403928000, 309], [1404014400, 245], [1404100800, 328],
    [1404187200, 431], [1404273600, 329], [1404360000, 348], [1404446400, 361],
    [1404532800, 184], [1404619200, 127], [1404705600, 236], [1404792000, 277],
    [1404878400, 333], [1404964800, 347], [1405051200, 301], [1405137600, 248],
    [1405224000, 253], [1405310400, 328], [1405396800, 369], [1405483200, 330],
    [1405569600, 444], [1405656000, 429], [1405742400, 313], [1405828800, 322],
    [1405915200, 346], [1406001600, 408], [1406088000, 376], [1406174400, 293],
    [1406260800, 249], [1406347200, 246], [1406433600, 212], [1406520000, 304],
    [1406606400, 316], [1406692800, 283], [1406779200, 180], [1406865600, 13]],
'key': 'Stream3'},
{'values': [[1403236800, 209], [1403323200, 303], [1403409600, 236],
    [1403496000, 341], [1403582400, 310], [1403668800, 361], [1403755200, 342],
    [1403841600, 335], [1403928000, 196], [1404014400, 197], [1404100800, 361],
    [1404187200, 368], [1404273600, 360], [1404360000, 345], [1404446400, 313],
    [1404532800, 174], [1404619200, 205], [1404705600, 294], [1404792000, 345],
    [1404878400, 382], [1404964800, 326], [1405051200, 436], [1405137600, 274],
    [1405224000, 251], [1405310400, 330], [1405396800, 365], [1405483200, 408],
    [1405569600, 517], [1405656000, 542], [1405742400, 438], [1405828800, 451],
    [1405915200, 511], [1406001600, 521], [1406088000, 376], [1406174400, 363],
    [1406260800, 282], [1406347200, 235], [1406433600, 268], [1406520000, 352],
    [1406606400, 425], [1406692800, 371], [1406779200, 210], [1406865600, 17]],
    'key': 'Stream4'},
{'values': [[1403236800, 251], [1403323200, 368], [1403409600, 356],
    [1403496000, 469], [1403582400, 456], [1403668800, 515], [1403755200, 509],
    [1403841600, 422], [1403928000, 290], [1404014400, 328], [1404100800, 467],
    [1404187200, 437], [1404273600, 505], [1404360000, 410], [1404446400, 434],
    [1404532800, 309], [1404619200, 330], [1404705600, 458], [1404792000, 423],
    [1404878400, 478], [1404964800, 507], [1405051200, 484], [1405137600, 319],
    [1405224000, 422], [1405310400, 475], [1405396800, 412], [1405483200, 511],
    [1405569600, 536], [1405656000, 551], [1405742400, 434], [1405828800, 451],
    [1405915200, 511], [1406001600, 503], [1406088000, 449], [1406174400, 433],
    [1406260800, 300], [1406347200, 272], [1406433600, 297], [1406520000, 454],
    [1406606400, 381], [1406692800, 400], [1406779200, 212], [1406865600, 18]],
    'key': 'Stream5'}];
```

The Javascript is:

```
var colors = d3.scale.category20();
keyColor = function(d, i) {return colors(d.key)};

var chart;
nv.addGraph(function() {
  chart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart()
                .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
                .x(function(d) { return d[0] })
                .y(function(d) { return d[1] })
                .color(keyColor)
                .transitionDuration(300);

  chart.xAxis
      .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d)) });

  chart.yAxis
      .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

  d3.select('#chart1')
    .datum(data)
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .call(chart)
    .each('start', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            d3.selectAll('#chart1 *').each(function() {
              console.log('start',this.__transition__, this)
              if(this.__transition__)
                this.__transition__.duration = 1;
            })
          }, 0)
      })

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
 });

  return chart;
});
```

I've also tried to modify things as found in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891420/nvd3-formatting-date-returns-always-1970-01-01) as shown below, but this doesn't work either.

```
var chart;
nv.addGraph(function() {
  chart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart()
                .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
                .x(function(d) { return new Date(d[0]); })
                .y(function(d) { return d[1] })
                .color(keyColor)
                .transitionDuration(300);

  chart.xScale = d3.time.scale();
  chart.xAxis
      .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d)) });

  chart.yAxis
      .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));
```

Comment: `{ return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d[0])) });`?

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes Replaced `.x(function(d) { return d[0] })` with `.x(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d[0])) })`. The plot no longer renders and the console shows lots of errors.

Comment: No, please replace the function inside `chart.xAxis.tickFormat()`. You replaced the wrong one.

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes That causes NaN to appear for all of the ticks on the x axis. `.tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d[0])) });`.

Comment: HHmmm...unless someone else spots the problem in short order, you might want to create a fiddle. It will be easier for folks to help you out.

Answer (score 5):

apparently, d3 uses 13 digits unix timestamp (including microseconds) and you have 10 digits unix timestamp. try doing this:

```
.tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d*1000)) });
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When posting code, please format code by indenting it with 4 spaces.

Comment: +1 Good job. This is the best answer. I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TtTr8/2/) that I generated accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed better with fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" is with the data. I changed the date formatting from assuming "%m/%d/%Y" to "%H:%M:%S". Here is the code change:

```
chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function (d) {
    // changed from %x to %X
    // see https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#user-content-format
    return d3.time.format('%X')(new Date(d))
});
```

I generated a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TtTr8/1/) for you to check.