# nvd3 Time Series Graph not getting plotted

Tags: angularjs, charts, nvd3.js

I am trying to get a basic NVD3 graph, and here's the code snippet.

```
$scope.options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'stackedAreaChart',
      height: 450,
      margin : {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 40
      },
      x: function(d){ return Date(d[1]);},
      y: function(d){return d[0];},
      useVoronoi: false,
      clipEdge: true,
      duration: 0,
      useInteractiveGuideline: true,
      xScale: d3.time.scale(),
      xAxis: {
        showMaxMin: false,
        tickFormat: function(d) {
            return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d));
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        tickFormat: function(d){
          return d;
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

The data that is fed to the chart is like this:

```
$scope.data = [
    {
      "key" : "mac1" ,
      "values" : [ [ 5000 , "2016-02-03T11:07:58.940Z"] , [ 5200 , "2016-02-03T11:08:09.862Z"] ]
    }
  ];
```

There's no line or stacked area in the graph.

The X-axis, which is the time series, has the dates of 1/1/1970.

I am unsure where I am going wrong. Help please?

A few similar stackoverflow questions didn't help were -

[nvd3 date formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891420/nvd3-formatting-date-returns-always-1970-01-01)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake I had done was this, `x: function(d){ return Date(d[1]);}` this line would return the date format and I was re-formatting the date again in the tickFormat.

Changing to `x: function(d){ return d[1];}` helped the graph to come up on the screen.

I also tried modifying the `duration: 100` yet the graph is unable to be refreshed from server. Any help here?